# Add event listener to every row in a dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a table that I am populating using a JSON file. The amount of JSON entries, and therefore table rows, can be any length. Each row contains a bootstrap dropdown button that has links used for things like renaming or deleting the table row.

I've tried several solutions I found online, most including a `foreach` loop, but I had lots of issues trying to implement those into my code.

```
function populate()
{
    $.getJSON(, {})
    .done(function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, items) 
        {
            table.append(
                `<tr>
                     <td>
                         <div class="btn-group dropdown">
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                 Actions
                             </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="renameEntry()">Rename</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>`
            )
        });
    });
}
```

As you can see, I've tried using an `onclick()` method to trigger a js function, but I don't know how to best differentiate between rows so the `onclick()` only affects the relevant row.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: post the relevant functions .. and explain exactly what is works on it and what is not .. but something I should say is No need for `forEach` loop at all

Comment: When you call the `onclick()` function, you can use `this` inside the function to get the dropdown item that was clicked (if you want a jQuery version of the dropdown item do `$(this)`). From there you can use dom traversal to get the correct row. That's what I'd do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need an element in this case `this` that will allow you to access the DOM element that has been clicked, that you will get back to the level with the `e` (you can give any name).
I do not know what you intend to do with this information, but in my example, I explain how to access the DOM element that was clicked.

Look at the code below, and I hope it will help you.

```js
function test(e) {
  e.style.background = "red";
}
```

```html
<div onclick="test(this)">
    <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the most intuitive and simple answer, thank you

Answer (score 2):

> using an onclick() method to trigger a js function

Is usually frowned upon because you're mixing presentation with logic.  Makes it difficult to debug.

If you're dynamically adding anything to the DOM and want click events occuring against these dynamic elements, JQuery provides a way to target them without performance penalty of bubbling event handlers, nor any dynamic adding of listeners as you add elements.

You can use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to target elements in a container.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.js-add-row').on('click', () => {
    $('.js-dyn-table').append('<tr><td>New Row <button class="js-hello">Hello</button> </td></tr>')
  });
  
  // Target the first container that has dynamic elements,
  // in this case the table
  // the second selector is the element that we want the event to occur on: .js-hello
  $('.js-dyn-table').on('click', '.js-hello', (e) => {
    // e.currentTarget is the element the event occured on
    var $btn = $(e.currentTarget);
    // closest will work it's way up parent html elements until it finds the first match
    var $tr = $btn.closest('tr');
    
    $tr.toggleClass('bg-yellow');
  });
});
```

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid green; 
  margin-top: 10px
}

.bg-yellow {
  background-color: Gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="js-add-row" type="button" value="Add Row">

<table class="js-dyn-table">
  <tr><td>Existing Row<button class="js-hello">Hello</button> </td></tr>
</table>
```